# Where are these non-default Vim settings stored if not in my .vimrc file?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, vim, vimrc

So when I press `:set` I see a bunch of settings that are not on my `~/.vimrc` file. (My guess is they're settings I've set years ago and don't remember).

So I do `:version` and get a path `$VIM/vimrc`, which is said to be "fall-back"ed by `usr/share/vimrc`. This is the "system vimrc".

I open the latter path, and the mystery settings are not in this vimrc file.

The only other path is the "user excrc file" at `$HOME/.exrc`, which I've no idea how to get to or what it is.

Anyone have any idea where the settings that show up when I command `:set` come from?

I'm on OS X (10.6).

Comment: What settings do you see there? Maybe just overall defaults? (Note, not a vim expert here)

Comment: small stuff like `background=dark`, which looks like something I would've chosen. Language set to English... only it's not in the main vimrc fail, and according to *UNIX for MAC OS X* (tutorial I'm reading), the `:set` command should display all non-default settings currently on. -- I'd like to have them all in one handy .vimrc file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of things Vim sets automatically if ~/.vimrc is present.  Among them is `'nocompatible'` which affects a number of other options.  Additionally, Vim does try to detect the proper values for other settings based on the environment.  For example, the proper value `'background'` can often be auto-detected by Vim if invoked from an Xterm or compatible terminal emulator.  The language settings will be based on your environmental variables.

Finally, you can run "`:scriptnames`" to see what files Vim has sourced since startup.  This should include showing you where the system `vimrc` is located, if it exists.

Comment: Oh ok. That makes sense, because I'm using the "dark" preset in iTerm.

Answer (score 1):

Try `/etc/vimrc` as this is the default for most Linux distros I've encountered and may also be the case for OS X.

Comment: doesn't look like there's a vim file in the OSX `/etc/`.

Comment: try /usr/share/vimrc

Answer (score 1):

To see where a particular option was last set, execute

```
:verbose set <option>?
```

To see the options that vim sets by itself, start vim as

```
vim -N -u NONE
```

then execute `:set`. In my case, running Vim 7.3.487 on Linux, I see

```
:set
--- Options ---
  helplang=en         scroll=11           ttymouse=xterm2
noloadplugins         ttyfast
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  background=light
```

To find out why any of those are set that way, use `:help`. For example, `:help 'ttyfast'` explains that it is set because vim determinded that my terminal is an xterm.